# Forge Elemenet properties

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, forge, autodesk-bim360

I am working on a project that retrieves our metadata from forge [using this API](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-metadata-guid-properties-GET/) after translating the Revit files on BIM360,
but I am running into some questions:

1- I am storing the elements (parameters/properties ) into external DB by using (IExternalID as unique ID)... my question is does the IExternal ID change if I update a parameter on Revit || modify the element. for example, if update the element on Revit what I will able to see: same IExternalID or different IExternalID since I updated the element
2- when is the External ID will be changed?
3- any news regarding SVF2 :D ? in order to track what exactly happened in the element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Cyrille and Jeremy :)
I was a great answer, in the end, I am trying to solve it by creating a new table in DB that has only the properties of the element, So every element (IExternal ID) will have different properties by the time this is my best thought in order to keep tracking on the element by the time.
Please correct me if you think I am missing something or I am wrong

thank you again :)

Answer (score 0):

Unique IDs (or ExternalID) are objects ID and do not change when you update, change a parameter of an object. It usually do not change either if you modify the object as well, but there it depends on the operation. For example if you split a wall into 2 pieces, you now got 2 objects, and a different set of IDs. But if you only move it, the ID remains as is. For SVF2, checkout [this article](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/svf2-public-beta-new-optimized-viewer-format).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Cyrille's helpful answer, The Building Coder shares a whole bunch of articles on various aspects of the Revit unique id in the topic group
on [Element Identifiers in RVT, IFC, NW and Forge](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/about-the-author.html#5.56).